# javascript ,jquery to check if an input field is only letters and not numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, if-statement, typeof

I'm trying to put some logic into my js to check that a user can only input letters into an input field and not numbers.  The two fields are for city and state. I know I should be using an if/else statement and possibly typeOf? Any help would be much appreciated! so then if numbers are present then I'd console.log and/or alert('no numbers or whatever'); I tried the first solution with only using html but that did not work for me and thanks for the first answer though!!!. The input fields are not inside of a form tag and when I wrap them in a form my js stops working.  Is there a way to check it another way?

```
        $submitBtn.on('click', function () {
        let city = $cityBox.val().trim();
        let state = $stateBox.val().trim();  // trying to figure out how to do it on both of these 

        //variables. 


       //below are 2 function to run inside this submit btn click.
       // savedHistory(city, state); 
       // dailyWeather(city, state);      
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the `$submitBtn`, it sounds like this is in a form, in which case you can use the `pattern` attribute to require that the input matches the pattern before the form is submitted. For only letters, use `[a-zA-Z]+` (one or more letters):

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
  <input pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

But since cities and states can have both letters *and* spaces, perhaps you should revise your requirement and permit spaces as well, by adding a space to the character set:

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+">
  <input pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

For a custom message, give the input a `title` attribute:

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" title="Only letters and spaces permitted">
  <input pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" title="Only letters and spaces permitted">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

No Javascript needed.